# install ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to install the tabulous ruby gem by following [this tutorial](http://rubysource.com/too-good-to-be-true-twitter-bootstrap-meets-formtastic-and-tabulous/)

I am getting stuck in a loop: run gem update => run gem => bundle install.

Can someone provide some information about how to proceed? I have already added the gem to Gemfile.

Here are the command outputs:

```
**22:16:35->gem update --system**
Updating RubyGems
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.8.24
Updating RubyGems to 1.8.24
Installing RubyGems 1.8.24
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:153: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/git/bin/ in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/gauntlet_rubygems.rb


**22:17:33->bundle install**
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:263: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/git/bin/ in PATH, mode 040777
Using rake (10.0.3) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.5.0) 
Using activesupport (3.2.11) 
Using actionpack (3.2.11) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.6) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.7) 
Installing tabulous (1.3.0) 
Gem::InstallError: tabulous requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.7. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself.
An error occurred while installing tabulous (1.3.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install tabulous -v '1.3.0'` succeeds before bundling.


22:18:03->gem install tabulous -v '1.3.0
> `
> '
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    Illformed requirement ["1.3.0\n`\n"]

**22:18:39->gem install tabulous -v 1.3.0**
ERROR:  Error installing tabulous:
    tabulous requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.7. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself.

22:26:25->gem update --system
Updating RubyGems
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.8.24
Updating RubyGems to 1.8.24
Installing RubyGems 1.8.24
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:153: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/git/bin/ in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/gauntlet_rubygems.rb
```

Comment: rey with sudo and check or try to manually down load and install

Comment: I think you are using the system ruby, so you'll need to sudo. But I highly recommend that you don't do that and install a ruby version manager like rbenv or rvm. Then you shouldn't have to sudo to install gems.

Comment: @Kasumi , curious. Whats the advantage of not having to sudo.

Comment: @codeObserver I believe it's not so much the advantage of not having to sudo, as it is the safety of using a ruby installation separate from your system ruby, that Kasumi is encouraging here.
Consider the fact that the system ruby has its own important code that it's expected to run, and then consider the consequences that altering the version, etc. of that ruby might have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Edit: I would also recommend doing as Kasumi commented and use rvm or rbenv. I had a hell of a time installing Ruby on Rails locally until I installed rbenv.

Comment: thanks. I had tried that command but without sudo . This worked !! Also will look into rbenv.